# How to install openssh in Crux Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, sshd, crux

In Crux Linux I already have installed SSH but when I use `ssh-keygen`, and try to use the command:

```
ssh localhost
```

to test SSH I get this error:

```
# ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
#
```

So I decided to reinstall `openssh` but without `apt-get` I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Apparently, Crux uses `pkgutils` as its package manager http://www.fukt.bsnet.se/~per/pkgutils/ However, I doubt that your problem is related to reinstalling `openssh`

Comment: Is your sshd running?

Comment: but if i don't have the software in the local,how can i install it from the net?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the client (and, I believe, also the server) installed. But you're not running the server on your machine (it's not started by default on Crux).

Add `sshd` to the `SERVICES` setting in `/etc/rc.conf`. See the [handbook](http://crux.nu/Main/Handbook2-7#ConfigurationVariables). This will take care of starting the SSH server at boot time. For now, run `/etc/rc.d/sshd start`.

As per the [FAQ](http://crux.nu/Wiki/Faq?from=Main.Faq#ntoc30), you may want to customize `/etc/hosts.allow` or `/etc/hosts.deny` first. Note that these files offer hostname-based protection, which is not always trivial to circumvent but far from absolute nonetheless. Ssh itself provides good protection against intruders (as long as you don't enable passwords, or make sure every user has a high-entropy password), so I recommend allowing SSH access to all (`sshd: ALL` in `/etc/hosts.allow`).

Comment: thx,ur answer helps too much

Answer (score 1):

Is your sshd running? `ps aux | grep sshd`.
Is it running on the standard port? `less /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the `ssh` daemon.

```
/etc/rc.d/sshd start
```

The location of the binary might be different, depending on how you installed it.

Comment: This is wrong. ``/etc/rc.d/sshd start``

Comment: @maxmackie The directory is still incorrect: `rc.d`, not `init.d`...